# Ruby on Rails select_tag selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selectedvalue

I'm having trouble getting the selected value using the select_tag.
On my new.html.erb, I have a following code:

```
<%= select_tag "dams_provenance_collection[subjectType][]",  options_for_select(subjectTypeArray), :prompt=>"Select subject type" %>
```

and on edit.html.erb, I want to use the selected value from new.html.erb as a default, so I tried:

```
<%= select_tag 'dams_provenance_collection[subjectType][]',  options_for_select(subjectTypeArray, params[:selected])  %>
```

but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to set selected value from new.html.erb as default in edit.html.erb? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<%= select_tag "dams_provenance_collection[subjectType][]", options_for_select(array_values, :selected => params[:option]) %>
```

Comment: I think this is wrong, you should pass `selected` opt to `select_tag` not to options

Comment: Or If you want to do it this way, just pass selected (default) as second parameter.

Comment: RTFM http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this:

```
= select_tag :chart_time_id, options_for_select(@times_collect, :selected => params[:num_days].present? ? params[:num_days].to_i : 7), {class: 'form-control selectpicker', 'data-style'=> "btn-info", required: true}
```

Just check param present or not, and using inline operater (if -else)