# how do i populate data on table using dropdown in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following dropdown:

`<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select Category"%>`

I am new in rails.I want to show data on the table when i click on any `Category` from this dropdown.Is there any way to do it only in Ruby code.

Comment: Do you want to filter data on a table on the basis of selected category in dropdown ?

Comment: yes,i want to filter data on a table on the basis of selected category in dropdown .

Comment: Please describe in details.. Which Data? Data of Categories table or associated table's?

Comment: I want to populate it's respective `Menu Items`.This `Menu` table contains `Category_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your view:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select Category"%>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>

<table>
  <% @object_for_table.each do |object| %>
    ----YOUR TABLE DATA HERE---
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Changes to action that is responsible for above view:

```
def search
  @object_for_table = params[:category].blank? ? Model.all : Model.where(category_id: params[:category])
end
```

Finally make changes in your js for submit form on category selection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select#category").change(function(){
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });

});
```

Comment: `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`.`<% @menus.each do |g| %>`

Comment: Your @menus object is nil. Update your code of view and action.

Comment: I have another problem. When the page gets refreshed the value gets lost in the dropdown .So, i want to hold that value until i clicked on the submit button.

Comment: Simply remove that jquery code. And set value of dropdown on the basis of params that you submitted before. Or assign that submitted param to a instance variable so you will get on view

Comment: It's not working, still getting the same problem.I have removed the  js code.How do i set value of dropdown on the basis of params.

Comment: consider on controller you get `params[:category]` then in controller create a instance variable from it like `@selected = params[:category]` then in view set selected on the basis of `@selected`

Comment: I have done the controller part....but in view how do i set the value in `select_tag`

Comment: i have used `@categories` in select_tag so how i put another instance variable in the dropdown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608003/ruby-on-rails-select-tag-selected-value & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347039/rails-select-tag-selected-value

Comment: <%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name", :selected => @selected), prompt: "Select Category"%>

Comment: In controller: `def new` ` if params[:category].present?` 
    ` @catId=params[:category]`
    ` end`
      `@menus2  = params[:category].blank? ? Menu.all : Menu.where(category_id: @catId)`  `end`    In menus/new:`<%= form_tag :controller=>'menus',:action=>'new' ,:method => 'get' do %>`
 `<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name",:selected=>@catId), prompt: "Select Category"%>`  `<%= submit_tag "Filter", :name => nil,class: "btn-orange" %> <%end%>`.After page gets refresh the value gets lost.

Comment: Try write hard coded category id for selected. Might not in right position. And let me know it works or not

Comment: yes it's working when i uesd `:selected=>41`.But i don't want to use hard code, it should be dynamic.

Comment: If it's working like that and you are able to get actual data in table then dropdown should also get initialized with value. try use `:selected=>@catId.to_i` . It's just a guess that selected value populate with integer in your case.

Comment: I am using this code in my controller: `def new` `if params[:category].present?` 
     `@catId=params[:category]`
     `end`
      `@menus2  = params[:category].blank? ? Menu.all : Menu.where(category_id: @catId)`.This is not working.If i push value if `present?`.